# iOS - Detect UITableViewCell being moved out of the visible view?

Tags: ios, uitableview

As soon as the cell is no longer visible on the screen I need to be notified.

UITableView already has a delegate method called `tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` but this delegate method never gets called. And yes I do have the delegate for my UITableView set.

Any other ways to detect a cell being removed? I need to be able to save the content (inputs) of this cell before it's being reused by another item.

**EDIT:**

According to the documentation `tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` is iOS 6 and higher API. Is there a way to achieve this on iOS 5?

Comment: Have you added the `UITableViewDelegate` and set Table view's delegate to `self`?

Comment: Yes, I specifically mentioned that in my question :)

Comment: What version of iOS are you testing on?

Comment: My Base sdk is iOS 6.0. This owrk on iPad 6.0 but not on iPAd 5.1

Comment: According to the documentation "Available in iOS 6.0 and later." So is there a way to do this on iOS 5?

Comment: `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` will return `nil` if the cell at specific index path is invisible. Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On versions of iOS older than 6.0, the table view doesn't send the `tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` message.

If you are using a subclass of `UITableViewCell`, you can get the same effect on older versions of iOS by overriding `didMoveToWindow`:

```
- (void)didMoveToWindow {
    if (self.window == nil) {
        // I have been removed from the table view.
    }
}
```

You may need to give your cell a (weak or unsafe_unretained) reference back to your table view delegate so you can send the delegate a message.

However, you can't rely only on `didMoveToWindow` for all versions of iOS.  Before iOS 6, a table view always removed a table view cell as a subview before reusing it, so the cell would always receive `didMoveToWindow` before being reused.  However, starting in iOS 6, a table view can reuse a cell *without* removing it as a subview.  The table view will simply change the cell's frame to move it to its new location.  This means that starting in iOS 6, a cell does **not** always receive `didMoveToWindow` before being reused.

So you should implement both `didMoveToWindow` in your cell subclass, and `tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` in your delegate, and make sure it works if both are called, or if just one is called.

Comment: Posted my answer before seeing this one, so will probably accept this one as answer, since it's really close to mine and resolves the problem

Answer (score 4):

I ended up using the combination of below to make sure that the logic applies to both iOS 5.0 and 6.0

**CELL LOGIC**

```
@protocol MyCellDelegate
- (void)myCellDidEndDisplaying:(MyCell *)cell;
@end

@implementation MyCell

// Does not work on iOS 6.0
- (void)removeFromSuperview
{
   [super removeFromSuperview];

   [self.delegate myCellDidEndDisplaying:(MyCell *)self];
}

@end
```

**VIEWCONTROLLER LOGIC**

```
@implementation MyViewcontroller

- (void)myCellDidEndDisplaying:(MyCell *)cell
{
   IndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPatForCell:cell];
   // do stuff
}

// Does not work on iOS below 6.0
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:
```

is only available in iOS6 and later.

One (albeit slow) way to accomplish what you are after would be to use the scrollView delegate methods to monitor when the tableview scrolls. From there, call:

```
NSArray *visiblePaths = [tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
```

and check for any changes to the array of visible paths.