# Cursor is not showing when calling becomeFirstResponder

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, text-cursor, becomefirstresponder

I have tableview which contains textfield in each cell, when user change value in, say, `textfield1` and click on `textfield2`, I reload data in `- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField` method, since it is changing number of rows in tableview, but in `textfield2` cursor is not visible, only on second time click it shows cursor. I know the problem is reloading of tableview because when I comment `reloadData` method call, textfield is working fine. I tried by saving tag of `textfield2` and after tableview finish reloading I called `becomeFirstResponder` message on `textfield2` but still it is not showing cursor.
Can anyone know how I can resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Calling `becomeFirstResponder` in `didEndDisplayingCell` is working fine, but this API is only available in iOS6.0 not less than this. I tried using `willDisplayCell`, but this is also not working, So can anyone tell, is there any other alternative which is available in iOS5.0 or this there any other way to handle this?

Comment: Can you not just insert/delete the rows that actually change without doing a full table reload?

Comment: Please check the following link. It might be helpful.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770903/ios-detect-uitableviewcell-being-moved-out-of-the-visible-view